# How do I set the line marker where my string will start? setw() does not achieve what I need it to

Tags: c++, new-operator

C++ How do I set the line marker where my string will start? setw() does not achieve what I need it to. I need the string to begin at a certain point and end whenever, seems like setw() does the exact opposite. I'll send what the final result needs to look like. Ignore the specifics on obtaining the desired numbers from the input file as I already have everything. I just can't seem to format it correctly on the print screen or in the output file.

[image: Example of required printscreen/file]

I have the headers and the actual content already worked out to provide the correct results. Again, I just can't get the layout to be what I need it to be. (P.S. I'm using a while loop to retrieve the information from a file. and the BP has been converted to int from string)

Here is my code so far. I'm not sure what is happening that is not allowing me to make it match the example above. I've tried every combination of `setw()`, left, right, internal, etc.

It may not be in order yet, but I was more worried about ensuring I had everything first, and then worrying about format and order. (My ofstream is in comment format while I print screen to check my progress. It will eventually be used. I also already know my file isnt being closed at the end.)

```
    ifstream inputfile;
            
                //ofstream outputfile;

    string Patient1;
    string Patient2;
    string Patient3;
    string fname;
    string lname;
    string bp;
    int pos;
    int systolic;
    int diastolic;
    string room;
    string stage;
    string risk;

    
    inputfile.open("E:\\Patient3E.dat");

                //Headers for output

    cout << "Note" << setw(5) << "Room" << setw(6) << "Name" << setw(23) << "BP" << setw(18) << "Diagnosis" << endl;
    cout << "----" << setw(5) << "----" << setw(26) << "------------------------" << setw(10) << "---------" << setw(17) << "---------------" << endl; 
    
    while (inputfile >> fname >> lname >> bp >> room)
        
                // Convert string to int for comparison with numbers

            {bp.find("/");
        pos = bp.find("/");
        bp.substr(0, pos);
        systolic = stoi(bp.substr(0, pos));
        diastolic = stoi(bp.substr(pos+1));

                    //else if for determining risk asterisks count

        if (((systolic >= 120) && (systolic < 140)) || ((diastolic >= 80) && (diastolic < 90))) 
            {risk = "   *";
            }
        else if (((systolic >= 140) && (systolic < 160)) || ((diastolic >= 90) && (diastolic < 99)))
            {risk = "  **";
            }
            else if ((systolic >= 160) || (diastolic >= 100))
                {risk = " ***";
                }
                else if ((systolic < 120) || (diastolic < 80))
                {risk = " ";
                }

        cout << left << setw(4) << risk << right << setw(5) << room << lname << ", " << fname;

                //else if statements for  adding + to systolic values equal to or greater than 120

        if (systolic < 120)
        {cout << setw(11) << systolic << "/";
        }
        else if (systolic >= 120)
                {cout << setw(10) << "+" << systolic << "/";
                }
        
                //else if statements for adding + after diastolic for values equal to or greater than 80
            
        if (diastolic < 80)
        {cout << setw (0) << diastolic;
        }
        else if (diastolic >= 80)
                {cout << setw(0) << diastolic << "+";
                }
            
                //else if statements for determining stage

        if (((systolic >= 120) && (systolic < 140)) || ((diastolic >= 80) && (diastolic < 90))) 
            {stage = "prehypertension";
            }
        else if (((systolic >= 140) && (systolic < 160)) || ((diastolic >= 90) && (diastolic < 99)))
            {stage = "stage 1";
            }
            else if ((systolic >= 160) || (diastolic >= 100))
                {stage = "stage 2";
                }
                else if ((systolic < 120) || (diastolic < 80))
                {stage = "Normal";
                }

            cout << stage << endl;

                
    }
        
    cout << "Summary" << endl;
    cout << "Count" << setw(13) << "Diagnosis" << endl;
    cout << "-----" << setw(23) << "-------------------" << endl;

                //pause funciton

    Pause();

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: I hope these aren't real medical data, but they look quite non-fake.

Comment: *How do I set the line marker where my string will start?* -- That is not a very descriptive title.  Second, we have no idea what code you have written, since you didn't post any.  Last, you could simply use a `std::string`, size it, and stick the data in the string in any position you want.  Then output the string in its entirety.

Comment: They're fake Haha sorry I should've mentioned this is for a class

Comment: I've also added my code to the original post to make it easier to understand what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Obviously thats not the entire code I've written, as I already have the entire template in place, extraction of data, comparisons for determining asterisks, plus signs, etc. This is just the portion that highlights my issue the most, of not being able to get the name to align with the beginning of the letter instead of the ",".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ^^^

Comment: I'd also like to point out that I can get away with adding "    " after the room number, but the issue still arises when I get to blood pressure due to the names varying in length.

Comment: And forgive me for anything that isn't considered normal behavior on this site. I'm brand new to this and don't know the common posting methods, how to post correctly, etc.

Comment: check out `std::left` and `std::right` [stream manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left). in this case I think you'd want `std::left`.

Comment: I'm not sure if any of that will help, since the names are varying in length but I'll play around with it to see @aradarbel10

Comment: Yeah idk, still not working for me.